# Verify if element exists and pass it to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', setMap);

function setMap() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
  // more code
}
```

I am using JQuery.

How can check if the element "map" exists ...

And call the function `setMap` only if it exists ...

And also pass it instead of defining it inside the `setMap` function.

Comment: No reason to rely on jQuery 'length' for this... native JavaScript works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', setMap);

function setMap() {
  var mapElement = $("#map");
  if(mapElement.length == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
  // more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `canvas` will be set to `null` if an element is not returned by `getElementById()`.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

> ***"How can check if the element "map" exists ..."***

By comparing your result of `getElementById` to `null`

---

> ***"And call the function setMap only if it exists ..."***

by using an `if()` statement

---

> ***"And also pass it instead of defining it inside the setMap function."***

Define a parameter on `setMap`,

```
function setMap(canvas) {
  // more code
}
```

and pass the element to it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
if (canvas != null) 
    setMap(canvas);
```

---

A jQuery solution that doesn't rely on querying the DOM again, is this:

```
$("#map").each(setMap);
```

And define your `setMap` parameters like this:

```
function setMap(i, canvas) {
  // more code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the `map` element with `getElementById` and then call `setMap` if `map` is not `null`.

```
var map = document.getElementById('map');
if(map) setMap(map);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Using Jquery:**

```
var canvas = $('map');
if(map.length){
  //element map exists


  // more code
}
```

**Using Javascript:**

```
var map= document.getElementById('map');
if ( map!= null) {//element map exists more code
}
```

Comment: Seems like overkill just to check for a DOM element. Creating a jQuery object and then walking the DOM again using getElementById.

Comment: @Steve: agreed -- why use jQuery for such a simple assertion?